# How to encode the Numeric code in iPhone

Tags: iphone, numeric, nsstringencoding

I am having some numerical code and i want to encode the "Numerical Code". So how can i encode the string?. I have tried with NSASCIIStringEncoding and NSUTF8StringEncoding, but it doesn't encoded the string. So please help me out.

Eg :

```
    &#304; -> İ 
    &#305; -> ı
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you have are Unicode code points, not strings. You don't need to specify a string encoding, because what you are dealing with aren't strings at all; they're just single characters. And an NSString does not have an "encoding" in this sense.

To get those characters into a string, you need to use:

```
[NSString stringWithCharacters: length];
```

For example: you don't want to be creating a string with the contents "304"; that's just a string of numbers. Instead, create a unichar with the value of 304:

```
unichar iWithDot = 304;
```

"Unichar" is just an unsigned short, so no pointer and no quotes; you are just assigning the code point to a numerical value. Bundle all of the characters you need into a C string and pass the pointer to stringWithCharacters.